# Token not present for a pod in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a deployment in a GKE cluster. The pod is assigned a service account. I can confirm that the pod has infact a service account using this command

```
kubectl get pod <pod-name>  -o jsonpath='{.spec.serviceAccount}' -n <namespace>
```

According to this doc here
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/access-api-from-pod/

There should be a directory **/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/** containing the token, created automatically, if service account is present. But when I check inside the pod there is no such directory. Does GKE has some different way of working?

Comment: All what you need to know is here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/workload-identity

Comment: Are you running on gke standard or autopilot mode ?